# Loopback Error 401 (Unauthorized) while accessing APIs

Tags: angular7, loopback

I am facing an issue in loopback, 401 (Unauthorized). Initially all APIs are working perfectly.

Now I set ACL for some of the models. After that I got an error 401 (Unauthorized) while accessing APIs

**Sample Code**

Eg: One of my model.json file

```
"acls": [
{
  "accessType": "*",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$unauthenticated",
  "permission": "DENY"
}
```

I got the accesstoken after login. I think the access token is not getting in in my API headers.

Answer (score 2):

you can also define ACS level. you DENY for all unauthorized user but also set permission for authorized  user like.

```
"acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "admin",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
     {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$unauthenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ]
```

principalId is define in my ROLE collection if you did't define any princepalId you can also use this.

```
{
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$authenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
```